# ABAP FuBa "BBP_UPDATE_ATTRIBUTES"

Tags: database, attributes, abap

I have a problem with the function module "BBP_UPDATE_ATTRIBUTES" in ABAP.

I want to upload some attributes with this FM. (APPRV_LIM | SPEND_LIM | BUDGET) These are the extended attributes which can be modified in SAP with (TCODE: PPOMA).

When I want to upload the attribute "APPRV_LIM" the output is very different to the input. I don´t know if I need to format it or anything else.

If someone has an answer or had a similar problem in the past, please help.

[image: Output and Input]

Comment: `the output is very different to the input` what is different? from where is the screenshot you put? it doesn't look like BBP_READ_ATTRIBUTES. The question is unclear

Comment: I don't understand the question either. To help you troubleshooting, I see in your screenshot the weird value `3.100.300.030.003,00` in screen field "Genehmigungslimit", which looks like the hexadecimal value `310030003000300030003000` (but truncated) which corresponds to the text `100000` encoded in  UTF-16LE (UTF-16 Little Endian)...

Comment: I want to put the value 100000 in the field "Genehmigungslimit" with the FM BBB_UPDATE_ATTRIBUTES.                                                   I am sorry the FM is "BBP_UPDATE_ATTRIBUTES"

Answer (score 0):

First, translate value as the field required then, you could use something like this:

```
 DATA: it_attr_p TYPE TABLE OF bbp_attributes,
       is_attr_p TYPE bbp_attributes.
     
    is_attr_p-attr_id = ''.
    is_attr_p-value_logsys = ''.
    is_attr_p-value(20) = ''.
    is_attr_p-value+20(10) = ''.
    is_attr_p-value+30(4) = ''.
    APPEND is_attr_p TO it_attr_p.
     
    CALL FUNCTION 'BBP_UPDATE_ATTRIBUTES'
      EXPORTING
        user_id_p           = 'USER ID'
        scenario_p          = 'BBP'
        start_date_p        = sy-datum
        end_date_p          = '99991231'
      TABLES
        it_attr_p           = it_attr_p
      EXCEPTIONS
        object_id_missed    = 1
        no_active_plvar     = 2
        object_not_found    = 3
        no_attributes       = 4
        times_invalid       = 5
        inconsistent_values = 6
        update_error        = 7
        ambiguous_position  = 8
        OTHERS              = 9.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
              WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
    ELSE.
      COMMIT WORK AND WAIT.
    ENDIF.
```